# How to avoid stateful dependency in pytest fixtures?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I am testing a database where methods in that database class have to be called one after another for the data to be operated on by the next method being tested.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def database():
    return database.Database()

# Expected results
result_1 = read_result(1)
result_2 = read_result(2)
result_3 = read_result(3)

def test_a(database):
    database.a() # modifies database fixture
    assert database.a.result == result_1
    
def test_b(database):
    database.b() # requires database fixture to have been modified by a()
    assert database.b.result == result_2
    
def test_c(database):
    database.c() # requires database fixture to have been modified by a() and b()
    assert database.c.result == result_3
```

This uses a pytest fixture that is module scoped, so it is reused by each test. This test above will work but only because it runs the tests in order. From what I know, this is stateful dependency and my tests aren't isolated, which is bad practice in testing.

What is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I see several options here:

- Make single test instead of three
- Use [pytest-ordering](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering) do define running order
- Precreate entities in DB for each test case and reuse them every run

Comment: Making it a single test doesn't allow the separate testing of `a`, `b`, and `c`. Ordering doesn't address my concerns about dependency. As for your last suggestion, you mean to say have 3 different database fixtures, one for each intermediate test step?